# Need Help; C# Returning a System.dataTable from an Object

Tags: c#, t-sql

I'm trying to create a class that can be called by a Parser method. Essentially I need to retrieve the value from SQL data column; my query only grabs one column, then return that value as one row in a System.DataTable for my CSVshredder to use. This is what I have so far but I keep getting this Error **"shredderAction.Transporter.MsgDataTable()': not all code paths return a value"**; what am I missing?

```
public class Transporter
{
    public static DataTable MsgDataTable()
    {
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Persons");
        DataRow tableRow;
        tableRow = table1.NewRow();

        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Sanitised for security");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 CAST(cast(msgdata as varbinary(max)) as varchar(MAX)) FROM [Sanitised].[dbo].[MSGQUEUE]";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        table1.Rows.Add(value);
        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: then I need to make it work for message batches.

Answer (score 2):

You method requires a return, check out its signature:

```
public static DataTable MsgDataTable() //DataTable is a return type
```

Thus, you got to return `DataTable` type to make it syntatically correct.

In your final line, return the `DataTable` that you have created:

```
sqlConnection1.Open();
table1.Rows.Add(value);
sqlConnection1.Close();
return table1; // add this
```

And the error should be gone.

Only if a function has signature of returning `void` you can have no `return` in its block

```
private void thisMethodRequiresNoReturn(){ //void requires no return
    //do something without return
}
```

Otherwise, if it has a return, then in the method block, you have to return type which matches that signature in **all possible paths**

```
private int thisMethodRequiresIntReturn(){ //void requires int return
    //do something without return - error
}

private int thisMethodRequiresIntReturn(){ //void requires int return
    int val = 0;
    return val; //this is ok
}

private int thisMethodRequiresIntReturn(){ //void requires int return
    int val = 0; 
    if (val > 0)
        return val; //this is not ok, not all path returning int
}

private int thisMethodRequiresIntReturn(){ //void requires int return
    int val = 0; 
    if (val > 0)
        return val; 
    return -1; //this is ok, all paths returning int
}
```

Comment: OMG,how did I miss my return?  TY; I guess I have been staring at my screen to long today.

Comment: If I wanted to batch it would just changing my select statement to "top 50" be the best?

Comment: @user2113405 "batch it"? "select statement to "top 50"" - If you want to get more than 1 query result then yes.. change it to any value you want. ;)